# Java, I'm not being able to print the whole response on the console

Tags: java, sockets

I can't print the whole response from the server on the console! , There are 3 ways to bypass this matter,

1. Add this header **Connection: close**
2. Replace **HTTP/1.1** with **HTTP/1.0**
3. Add this **s.close();** // **Socket.close();**

I can't close the connection because I want to send more than once at the same connection,

I just want to print the whole response without closing the connection.

And this is my code:

```
            String Ch2 = "";


            sops.write(my_UTF8Byte);
            

            while((Ch2 = reader.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println(Ch2);
                //sops.write(my_UTF8Byte);
                Thread.sleep(10);
                
            }
            
        //s.close(); This will solve the problem
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say does not print whole response, it is missing the last line? Check by doing a char at a time not readLine:

```
int ch;
while((ch = in.read()) != -1)
{
    System.out.print((char)ch);
}
```

Comment: Many professional programmers could not solve this problem, This indicates that you are a professor of programming! I cannot express my thanks to you! You're number one Thank you very much dear

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem a long time ago.  Calling flush() on your OutputStream should solve your problem.

```
sops.flush
```

Comment: I called `sops.flush();` , Same problem ! it didn't print the whole response, And thank you very much, Your input is appreciated:)